# Core Plot graph bar disappears while scrolling beyond halfway

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I created a gantt chart using CorePlot's range plot. I added horizontal scrolling and it's working fine, however, every time I scroll horizontally, the graph bar disappears once 50% of is off the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's an example of the chart before scrolling:
[image: Chart before scrolling]

The chart after scrolling and the bar disappeared marked in blue.
[image: graph bar disappears]

THANKS

EDIT: I Found this this method, but don't know how to make the modification.

```
-(void)drawRangeInContext:(CGContextRef)context
            lineStyle:(CPTLineStyle *)lineStyle
            viewPoint:(CGPointError *)viewPoint
          halfGapSize:(CGSize)halfGapSize
         halfBarWidth:(CGFloat)halfBarWidth
          alignPoints:(BOOL)alignPoints
{
    if ( [lineStyle isKindOfClass:[CPTLineStyle class]] &&   !isnan(viewPoint->x) && !isnan(viewPoint->y) ) {
        CPTAlignPointFunction alignmentFunction =     CPTAlignPointToUserSpace;

    CGFloat lineWidth = lineStyle.lineWidth;
    if ( ( self.contentsScale > CPTFloat(1.0) ) && (round(lineWidth) == lineWidth) ) {
        alignmentFunction = CPTAlignIntegralPointToUserSpace;
    }

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // centre-high
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->high) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x, viewPoint->y + halfGapSize.height);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x, viewPoint->high);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // centre-low
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->low) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x, viewPoint->y - halfGapSize.height);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x, viewPoint->low);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // top bar
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->high) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x - halfBarWidth, viewPoint->high);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x + halfBarWidth, viewPoint->high);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // bottom bar
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->low) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x - halfBarWidth, viewPoint->low);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x + halfBarWidth, viewPoint->low);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // centre-left
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->left) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x - halfGapSize.width, viewPoint->y);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->left, viewPoint->y);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // centre-right
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->right) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->x + halfGapSize.width, viewPoint->y);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->right, viewPoint->y);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // left bar
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->left) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->left, viewPoint->y - halfBarWidth);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->left, viewPoint->y + halfBarWidth);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    // right bar
    if ( !isnan(viewPoint->right) ) {
        CGPoint alignedHighPoint = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->right, viewPoint->y - halfBarWidth);
        CGPoint alignedLowPoint  = CPTPointMake(viewPoint->right, viewPoint->y + halfBarWidth);
        if ( alignPoints ) {
            alignedHighPoint = alignmentFunction(context, alignedHighPoint);
            alignedLowPoint  = alignmentFunction(context, alignedLowPoint);
        }
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, alignedHighPoint.x, alignedHighPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, alignedLowPoint.x, alignedLowPoint.y);
    }

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    [lineStyle setLineStyleInContext:context];
    [lineStyle strokePathInContext:context];
    CGPathRelease(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these vertical or horizontal bars? It looks like they are vertical. Once the bar location (the center of the bar) is outside the visible plot area, the bar is hidden.

Comment: These are actually horizontal bars. Is there a way I can unhide these?

Comment: Could you point me to the class that handles the hiding of the bar and I can possibly modify it to not hide when the center is outside the visible plot area.

Comment: Look at the drawing methods in `CPTBarPlot`.

Comment: I'm actually using CPTRangePlot to draw this graph.

Comment: So I found the CPTRangePlot draw in context method. I don't know how to modify it so the bars will not hide. Could you please provide some additional guidance.

Comment: I added the range plot code snippet in the question.

Comment: The range plot uses the `-calculatePointsToDraw:numberOfPoints:forPlotSpace:includeVisiblePointsOnly:` method to determine which data points to draw.

Comment: Cool that works. Thanks